How to stop docker on vm shutdown under Linux
I have 3 dockers container running, and i want stop container before shutdown the vm.
I create one file : /etc/systemd/system/unmount-disks.service


[Unit]
Description=Démontage des disques externes et NAS avant arrêt
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=docker.service shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/unmount_disks.sh
RemainAfterExit=true
Environment="PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

[Install]
WantedBy=halt.target reboot.target shutdown.target



and then the /usr/local/bin/unmount_disks.sh :


#!/bin/bash

# Arrêter tous les conteneurs sauf GitLab Runner et Portainer Agent

for CONTAINER in $(docker ps -q); do
    CONTAINER_NAME=$(docker inspect --format '{{.Name}}' $CONTAINER | sed 's/\///g')
    echo "Traitement du conteneur : $CONTAINER_NAME..."

    if [ "$CONTAINER_NAME" == "gitlab-runner" ] || [ "$CONTAINER_NAME" == "portainer_agent" ]; then
        echo "Conteneur $CONTAINER_NAME ignoré..."
    else
        echo "Arrêt du conteneur $CONTAINER_NAME..."
        docker stop $CONTAINER
    fi
done



But i have this error :


-- Boot 0a7bed5f09ac4ab1b414124571f070cc --
unmount_disks.sh[3685]: error during connect: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.47/containers/json": EOF



It seems the docker service is shutdown before my script ?
If i run the script under root manually, everything is working.

Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.47/contai Check DOCKER_HOST varibale

@KamilCuk DOCKER_HOST was empty, i add this at start of my script : export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock but still have the same error, i change ExecStart to ExecStop but not working too :(

You error is truncated - ends with > . Check full error message. If you are using less, type arrow to the right.

@KamilCuk i just update my post with the full error

EOF means just that - docker was listening for a response, but there was the end. I suspect docker.service is getting killed before your job is executed, check systemd.unit documentaiton about Before= stuff. Maybe put your script to PreExit hook to docker.service.

Here is what I do:
Create your script service,
/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service
containing the following:
[Unit]
Description:myservice
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/unmount_disks.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


The main difference is the ExecStop where i use an ExecStart, what is the difference ?

You want to run the script when shutdown (stop), but not at start up.

Ok got it working with :
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target

And in my script :
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock

